# Mypy generic class in stub file

Tags: python, generics, stub, mypy

I'm toying around with adding type stubs to a library that has a collection class called `List`, which is essentially a wrapper around the builtin `list`. For all practical purposes you can suppose it looks like this:

```
# library.py
class List:
    def __init__(self, *values):
        self.values = values
```

Now, in my stub file `library.pyi` I have:

```
# library.pyi
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Iterable
T = TypeVar('T')
class List(Generic[T]):
   def __init__(self, *values: T) -> None: ...
```

I'd like typing to fail if I do something like:

```
# client.py
from library import List
def f() -> List[str]:
    return List(*range(10))
```

However `mypy client.py` exits with 0. Moreover the `python client.py` fails with `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`.

My understanding was that type hints did not have any impact on runtime. Thats clearly wrong. Can someone correct my mental model of how type hints work?

Moreover, is there any to get what I want (i.e have `mypy client.py` fail)?

Answer (score 6):

In order to understand what's going on, I think it'd be helpful to first review some background material.

In Python 3.0, Python added a new language feature known as *function annotations*. Function annotations, by themselves, have nothing to do with type annotations – they're simply a way to attach arbitrary information to functions.

Basically, what Python does is it takes whatever annotations you include, evaluates them, then adds them that function's `__annotations__` field. For example, try running the following code:

```
def foo(x: 3 + 4 * 5, y: [i + 1 for i in range(4)]) -> max(3, 4):
    pass

print(foo.__annotations__)
```

If we run this, we'll get:

```
{'x': 23, 'y': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'return': 4}
```

That is, Python will run `3 + 4 * 5`, then `[i + 1 for i in range(4)]`, then `max(3, 4)`, then attach that data to `__annotations__`. After it finishes doing so, Python will do nothing else.

In a nutshell, this means that...

1. Python must still evaluate each individual annotation, which must be a valid Python expression
2. But after doing so, annotations are ignored.

So, this means that when we're using specifically type hints, each type hint is individually evaluated/must be a valid expression during function-definition-time, but then is ignored by the Python runtime afterwords.

(As a caveat, this behavior may change slightly in the future: because we have to evaluate each annotation, using type hints *does* introduce a slight performance penalty – there are some talks about maybe changing Python so in the future, the expressions are stored as strings in `__annotations__` rather then being immediately evaluated.)

---

Now, taking all that into account, let's look at your program. When Python itself runs your program, it'll completely ignore your `.pyi` file. When it encounters:

```
from library import List

def f() -> List[str]:
    return List(*range(10))
```

...it'll first evaluate `List[str]` then attach that resulting object to `f.__annotations__`.

But we run into a problem! Your `List` type doesn't support the `__getitem__` protocol, so it doesn't know what to do with the `[str]` bit! So your code crashes.

The easiest ways to repair this are to either...

1. Repair your class in `library.py` so it also extends `Generic[T]` (when you extend that class, it does some metaprogramming so that doing `List[str]` works).
2. Switch to using the comment based syntax in `client.py` – that is, do:

   ```
   def f():
       # type: () -> List[str]
       ...
   ```

   ...since comments *are* genuinely completely ignored by the Python runtime, there's now no need to change `List` class in any way – the stubs will be sufficient for mypy.

   (What we're doing here is that mypy will completely ignore `library.py` and will only look at `library.pyi` – so, it doesn't care if `library.py` makes the `List` class generic or not.)
3. Write `List[str]` as a string:

   ```
   def f() -> 'List[str]':
       ...
   ```

   Mypy, and other PEP 484-compliant type checkers lets people put type hints in strings as a way of "forward declaring" types as necessary, but there's no reason why we can't just encode everything as a string (apart from how it looks a little messy).

I'd recommend approach 1, since approaches 2 and 3 are a bit hacky and fragile.

Answer (score 1):

The whole reason it fails is because the typing stub has no effect on the runtime.

The return annotation of `def f() -> List[str]` is evaluated at runtime. This fails as your library's `List` does not inherit from `Generic[T]`, so `List[str]` throws an error.

Also, the annotation for a variadic argument should be the type of every argument. I.e., `*values: Iterable[T]` means that every item should be an iterable of the type. You probably meant `*values: T`.

As for why it fails, it might just be a bug in mypy. Try making a typestub for `__new__` instead, as `__new__` determines the type of the object. For example:

```
class List(Generic[T]):
    def __new__(cls, *values: T) -> List[T]: ...
    def __init__(self, *values: T) -> None: ...
```

Comment: > The whole reason it fails is because the typing stub has no effect on the runtime.

[...]


> The return annotation of `def f() -> List[str]` is evaluated at runtime

I think what confuses me is the difference between a stub and a type hint. My mental model was that both were essentially stripped before the code was executed. What does it mean that `def f() -> List[str]` is evaluated at runtime?